# Can you use either "I hope this comes in handy for you" or "I hope this comes in useful for you"?

Tags: sentence

"I hope this comes in handy/useful/helpful for you"

Can I use any of the three words? Regardless of specifics. And do I need to drop the "in" in there?

Comment: 'Comes in handy' (in my experience) is an idiomatic saying. The other two are not expressed like that. _I hope this is useful/helpful to you_ is what I would say. Or _I hope this comes in handy_. 'Handy' is for everyone, not just a single person.

Comment: Have you looked up the three words in a dictionary? Compared their meanings and usages? Do you still need help?

Comment: @Kris , not anymore, but Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on where you are and what kind of English is spoken there.

*“I hope this comes in handy for you.”*

I have seen and heard this one used a lot in American English.

*“I hope this comes in useful for you.”*

I have seen this one used in British English, here and there.

*“I hope this comes in helpful for you.”*

I’ve never seen or heard this one used anywhere. Maybe it’s in use
somewhere, but I haven’t encountered it.